# CiviCRM selectively generating receipts/invoices for contribution pages

Tags: civicontribute, email, receipts

This could be an email deliverability issue - but I thought I would check to see if there is more I can do to troubleshoot. Many people are saying they are not receiving receipts and invoices when they make a contribution via our Drupal webform - but it seems to work when I do it.

I am on 5.18.2 - Is there any way to see a copy of the receipt that was generated?

Or tips on troubleshooting?

Comment: can you clarify - the receipts are presumed to be going out because you have selected a civi Contribution page that has Receipting turned on? If so, why not BCC yourself on that. Also consider using the Transaction Mail extension as this creates an Activity for all such outgoing mail.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I would upvote this if it were an answer.

Comment: done.thx for encouragemtn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using the [Transaction Mail extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/transactional-emails) as this creates an Activity for all such outgoing mail

or

since receipts are presumably going out because you have selected a civi Contribution page that has Receipting turned on why not BCC yourself on that

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that the last major release was updated in 2017 - but the master was updated 6 months ago - should we use the master? It looks like a release was planned but never processed

Comment: Should be released today when the cron job runs on civi side